# Django and SSL Server

Tags: python, django, ssl

I'm using a Django-SSLServer add-on with my Django app. As found at: [here](https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver)

For some reason when I run the server (using PyCharm), my static content doesn't render properly (if at all!). However, when I run the built in HTTP server, it renders the static files fine.

How can I re-route my site so that static works for HTTPS? I'm using the built in server with Django.

Thanks!

Comment: Update your STATIC_URL to use https?

Comment: What should it look like? O_O At the moment it's /static/

Comment: Have you tried to set it to https://localhost:8000/static/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your urls.py you should map your static path ie:

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':   settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

or alternatively,

```
from django.conf import settings
...
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.STATIC_DOC_ROOT}),
```

This should render your settings files while `DEBUG=False`

Hope this helps!